# Finding the Invariant Subspaces and Eigenvectors from Jordan Normal Form

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Say we have a matrix $M$, an invertible matrix $P$ and a Jordan matrix $J$ such that
$$
P^{-1} M P
=
J
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Say I want to find the eigenspace for $M$.
Intuitively, I would say that 
$$
\left\langle
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rangle,
$$
but I have no idea if this is correct.

Intuitively I would also say that the list of invariant subspaces of $M$ would be:
$$
\left\langle
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rangle,
\quad
\left\langle
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
2\\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
2\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\rangle,
$$
and then any combination of the "eigenspaces"
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
And then of course $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and $0$.

Am I correct? If not, is there any way of finding the eigenspaces and invariant subspaces of $M$ from the Jordan normal form $J$.

Answer (score 1):

You're  right: the eigenvectors are indeed ${}^{\mathrm t\mkern-1mu}(0,0, 1,0)$ and ${}^{\mathrm t\mkern-1mu}(1,0, 0,0)$, BUT when their coordinates are calculated in the new (Jordan) basis. To have their coordinates in the standard basis, just apply the change of basis matrix $P$. This means the eigenvectors are  simply the 1st and 3rd columns of $P$.

Similarly for the generators of the invariant subspaces.